# Rails select by group with Postgresql?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql

I have a model named `Program`, which has 'directory_id'、'id'、'user_id' columns, I want to select all the programs group by directory:

```
@programs = Program.select("programs.directory_id, programs.id, programs.user_id").group(:directory_id).page(params[:page])
```

The error is:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "programs.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  programs.directory_id, programs.id FROM "programs"  ...
                                       ^
: SELECT  programs.directory_id, programs.id FROM "programs"  GROUP BY directory_id LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Why do you want the group() clause here?  Normally GROUP BY is used with aggregates (e.g. SUM, COUNT, etc), and you have none in your select() clause.  What output are you hoping to get?

Comment: Thanks for remind me , I think I just want to sort by directory_id :), so the program can display by group